# Use sql with java - compiled into .jar - "ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, sql, jar

I wanted to try using SQL with Java, so I downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar.

I'm using Eclipse, so I went into Eclipse, Project -> Properties and added the jar files.

I also added the following to my classpath:

1. C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\com\mysql\jdbc\;
2. C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;

It runs fine in Eclipse, but when I run my. Jar file I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "when I run my jar file"? *How* are you launching it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` isn't in your classpath when you run your jar.

Inside your `.jar` file there should be a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. You need an entry in that file for your classpath that points to where the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` file is located:

```
Class-Path: path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
```

Note this can be local to your jar. A common way to do it is to have a `lib` subdirectory where your jar is located that contains the other jars yours depends on:

```
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
```

Comment: If I have it in my jar, how would that look?
../the-jar-file.jar
?

Comment: You can't have it in your jar.

Comment: Well, for the sake of completeness, you don't *need* that, you just need to make sure it's on the classpath when executing. This is one way of doing that. (And unless it's being distributed, not sure it's the best, but that's a different discussion :)

Comment: If someone else wants to run it I have to put the jar and the mysql...jar into a folder? That sucks

Comment: Well this was weird..
When I add the Class-Path: to my manifest file, it gives me a "Cannot find the main class "Main".....
If I don't include the Class-Path in the manifest file it will say classNotFound com.mysql.Driver

Comment: @Dave - the problem is that if you're running it with -jar I believe any externally set classpath is ignored, so ... it depends on how you're doing it.

Comment: Why can't it find the main-class "Main" when I add the Class-Path?

Comment: @BrianRoach Yep, if you're running it with -jar.

Comment: @user1021085 See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635136/how-to-set-default-main-class-in-java) regarding the `Main-Class` manifest property.

Comment: But my manifest file already includes "Main-Class: Main". The file is called Main, the methos called main.
And as I said, if I remove the Class-Path from the manifest file, I get the class not found (which means it found the main class?).

Comment: I tried making a new java file, which just outputs something, created a new manifest and made it into .jar and it works.
Problem seems to be with the sql java program only..

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath for the mysql .jar is most likely off. Is your jar located nearby the mysql jar? (If its not being pointed to it) To test this, you can place the two in the same directory and see if it runs.