# red5 work on eclipse but not from red5.bat or red5.sh

Tags: java, eclipse, red5

Hi i did followed the docs on google

[Red5 Media Server - Workspace Setup Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11ju06wbnEdC3ay0VuUxpKcXIoSx5NaHruNKuZQ4yOCk/edit#)

and i have my server work great and after i finished my red5 application and want to upload it at my deployment server  {linux}
i can't start it up 
i get the Could not find or load main class  org.red5.server.bootstrap

but when i debug it from the eclipse it's working very well

i did tried to rename files 
red5-server-1.0.jar
red5-server-1.0-bootstrap.jar

and even i change there names to the current relese

```
mv red5-server-1.0-bootstrap.jar red5-server-1.0.2-RC3-bootstrap.jar
```

but with no luck

any ideas will be helpful

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its Resolved by rename

red5-server-1.0-bootstrap.jar

boot.jar

many thanks 
hope that well help some one in the future

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the Main-Class entry in the manifest file of your jar file. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) tutorial

Comment: where to locate the red5 manifest file i searched whole of my red5 and i didnt find any file with the name manifest .

Comment: If you create the jar using eclipse, see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12811630/187343

Comment: well the red5 server are build with maven through the eclipse but it's not just a single app to determine which application class is the stating point