# How to work with NetBeans IDE 8.2 on Windows 7 64-bit with JDK

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been having trouble using NetBeans IDE 8.2 with JDK on Windows 7 64-bit. NetBeans can compile code, but doesn't run it. I've downloaded all of the necessary files and programs and even consulted with a computer programming teacher, but I haven't been able to work around this issue. The URL displays an image that shows what I get back after attempting to run a code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsEvx.png

I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks,

--Sam

Comment: you are not running your `TestClass`

Comment: Your computer programming teacher should have spotted this.

Comment: He did in fact notice that the files were in a package, not an individual class. However, he couldn't see everything, as he couldn't come to my house directly.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaApplication1.java` is still set as your main class.

To change your main class, go into Project Properties -> Run and change "Main Class" to `TestClass.java`.

Essentially, the compiler is still running whatever main function is found in `JavaApplication1.java`.

@notyou Also mentioned how you can right click a file and run it directly, instead of changing the project settings. I used to use this but it slipped me! This is super useful.

I'm pretty sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635136/how-to-set-default-main-class-in-java) question has some answers for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try when I'm back on my PC later today.

Comment: You can also right-click on the file and click Run File.