# GUI in netbeans will not pop up after running

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to work on a project for school but can't seem to find the answer to it. I try running one of my NetBeans projects with 2 forms but all it says is "Build Successful".

Here is my Main

https://i.stack.imgur.com/90NcU.png

EDIT: It seems to be something to do with "Containing the main class" but cannot seem to find how to do that

Comment: Is your project or run configuration definitely set to use u2a2_birthday_chem.Human_CheM as its start-up class? You may be running some other class by accident.

Comment: How do I configure that?

Comment: I think it's https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860099 although the question there is about package configuration not run configuration, but IIRC it's the same thing.

Comment: It says that it is configured to u2a2_birthday_chem.Main_CheM .  Which IS my main class for the 2 forms

Comment: OK, that looks right then. I don't remember NetBeans well sorry: is there a console on the debug view that would show you any error output when you run the app and it fails? Can you put a breakpoint on the first line of your main and run in debug mode to step through and see what happens?

Comment: Also every time I try to run the Jpanel Forms individually, it says that Class "u2a2_birthday_chem.Human_CheM" does not have a main method

Comment: I found the problem. I was supposed to create a Jframe form not a Jpanel form. Thanks for your help. Sorry for the time.

Comment: No problem! Glad you solved it and sorry I didn't really help.