# Nbeans cant find or load main class

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

Hello good day this is the first object oriented class, and I throw this error? How do I fix it? Thank you.
ERROR
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ Suma2 ---
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.suma2.suma.SumaMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.suma2.suma.SumaMain
Command execution failed.

There are two codes, here is one

```
package com.mycompany.suma2.suma;
 
 
public class SumaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         
         
        System.out.println("Give me the first value ");
        int valueOne=sc.nextInt();
 
  System.out.println("Give me the first value");
        int valueTwo = sc.nextInt() ;
         
         
        Sum values = new Sum(valueOne, valueTwo){
        values.Print();
    }                    
}
```

Here the other

```
 
 
  
public class Sum {
        private int vOne, vTwo, Result ;
     
    public Sum (int valueOne , int valueTwo ) {
           this.vOne = valueOne ;
        this.VTwo = valueTwo ;
        }   
    public void Operation(){
    Result = vOne +vTwo ;
     
    }
    public void Print(){
        Operation();
        System.out.println("The result of the sum is : + Result ");
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set default main class in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635136/how-to-set-default-main-class-in-java) specifically see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534598 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860099

Comment: Show us your maven pom.xml file and folder structure.