# Export JAR with Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

How to export java project to JAR with Netbeans ? I cannot find options like in Eclipse.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602537/producing-executable-jar-in-netbeans

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to enable the option

`Project Properties -> Build -> Packaging -> Build JAR after compiling`

(but this is enabled by default)

Comment: How would I pack all of the required library files into the JAR automatically using Netbeans ?

Comment: @kevingreen: You would need to overwrite the ant target and do it "manually". There is no automatic feature to build a "fat" jar

Comment: There's an option now in that menu: Copy Dependent Libraries.

Comment: eclipse is much easier than this

Answer (score 19):

Do you mean *compile* it to JAR? NetBeans does that automatically, just do "clean and build" and look in the "dist" subdirectory of your project. There will be the JAR with "lib" folder containing the required libraries. These JAR + lib are enough to run the application.

If you disable "Compile on save" in the project properties, then it is no longer necessary to do "clean and build", simply "build" will suffice in most cases. This will save time if you want to change just a bit of the code and rebuild the JAR. However, note that NetBeans sometimes fails to handle dependencies and binary compatibility properly, which will lead to a faulty JAR throwing "no such method" or other obscure exceptions. Therefore, if you made a lot of changes since the last full rebuild and even remotely unsure that it will still work even if some classes aren't recompiled, then you must still do a full "clean and build" in order to get a perfectly working JAR.

Comment: if you don't have a dist folder, you need to explicitly run 'clean and build' even though you may have already been compiling and running your program.

Answer (score 11):

It does this by default, you just need to look into the project's `/dist` folder.

Comment: all I see is build, nbproject, and src for folders under my project's folder.

Comment: figured it out: had to explicitly run 'clean and build' first

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click your project folder.
2. Select Properties.
3. Expand Build option.
4. Select Packaging.
5. Now Clean and Build your project (Shift +F11).
6. jar file will be created at your_project_folder\dist folder.