# connection to mysql server failed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

```
x1.instance3650.db.xeround.com-nino_db 
[chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.rehash()]   
this is con null [.()]   
connection to MySQL server failed 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:  
Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 
'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "chatserver"'.  
[chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.connect()]  
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"  [.()] 
java.lang.NullPointerException [.()]  at   
chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.ensureConnected(MySqlConnection.java:105) [.()]  at 
chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.getServerConfig(MySqlConnection.java:936) [.()]  at 
chatserver.objects.ServerConfig.loadConfigFromSql(ServerConfig.java:57) [.()]  at 
chatserver.objects.ServerConfig.<init>(ServerConfig.java:49) [.()]  at 
chatserver.objects.Server.<init>(Server.java:36) [.()]  at 
chatserver.objects.Server.getInstance(Server.java:88) [.()]  at 
chatserver.main.ServerMain$1.run(ServerMain.java:24) [.()]  at 
java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209) [.()]  at 
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597) [.()] at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269) [.()]  
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184) [.()]  
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174) [.
()]  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169) [.()]  at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161) [.()]  at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122) [.()]
```

This is thrown by the following block of code..

```
try {
     //conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:chatserver");
     // Joshua - change
     // dbPassword = "";
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":"
                  + dbPort + "/" + dbDatabase + "?" + "user=" + dbUser
                    + "&"
                    + "password=" + dbPassword);
     lastMySqlActionTime = new Date().getTime();
} catch (SQLException e) {
     System.out.println("this is con "+conn);
     ServerLog.logError("connection to MySQL server failed "+e);
     return false;
}
```

I can get access to the databases through command prompt and use database...it is not throwing error any error in driver...

plz some one can help me..thank you

Comment: could you please format your question appropriately? The error message wrapped and indented correctly and the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stacktrace and code snippet available it seems your `dbPort` is `chatserver`, whereas port is an int like `3306`, hence while parsing it as Integer it is failing and giving you `NumberFormatException`.

So instead of

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:chatserver")
```

try with this

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chatserver")
```

Complete connection string will look like below:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chatserver",
                            "root", "root");
```

In above you can place your username, password, dbPort, databasename e.t.c.

Here I am assuming you want to connect to a schema named as chatserver

Comment: thank u mprabhat i sloved that problem but i ve encounter a new problem.I run that code n it runs smoothly in my netbeans but when i try to run the jar file of this particular project it gaves an error

localhost-myblechat [chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.rehash()] 
connection to MySQL server failed [chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.connect()] 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"java.lang.NullPointerException
atchatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.ensureConnected(MySqlConnection.java:100) 
chatserver.sql.MySqlConnection.getServerConfig(MySqlConnection.java:931)

Comment: glad, you can check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498047/export-jar-with-netbeans) for Jar Export in Netbeans or can start a new Question for that.

Comment: it worked mprabhat...jar files are created in dist folder...and i also found one jar file in my folder name "store" so i run it...so now when i run the jar file of my dist folder it worked....thank you 4 ur help...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:chatserver");
```

You get a NumberFormatException, because port number should be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code below, and try to implement it as its here.... i hope it will run smoothly.. Once you start getting your desired query result, modify it to your heart content for further R&D.

Please `change the password and username` in this program

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import com.my.views.*;


public class DBDiary {

    Connection conn;
    EntryDisplay entryD;


    public DBDiary(){

        this.getConn();

    }

    public Connection getConn(){

        try {
            conn = getConnection();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
        }
           return conn;
    }


    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        String drivers = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";

        System.setProperty(drivers,"");

        return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

    }

    public void createTable() {

        Statement stat = null;
        String sql = "create table items(item varchar(30), cost DOUBLE(12,3),day integer,month varchar(15), year integer);";
        if (conn != null){

            try {

                 stat = conn.createStatement();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
            }

            if (stat != null){

                try {
                    stat.executeUpdate(sql);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //System.out.println("Table already Exists");
                }       
            }

        }
    }


    public void addItems(String item, double cost,int day, String month, int year) {

        PreparedStatement pstat = null;

        String sql = "INSERT INTO ITEMS Values(?,?,?,?,?);";

        if (conn != null){

            try {

                 pstat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
            }

        }

        if (pstat != null) {

            try {

                 pstat.setString(1, item);
                 pstat.setDouble(2, cost);
                 pstat.setInt(3, day);
                 pstat.setString(4, month);
                 pstat.setInt(5,year);
                 pstat.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Insertion of the entry was unsuccessful");
            }
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DBDiary db = new DBDiary();
    db.createTable();
    db.addItems("Cards", 40.00,29, "Mar", 2012);


    }
```