# Unable to execute JAR file on another PC

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jar

I have created a Swing GUI using NetBeans, and I am able to execute it on my local machine successfully. But whenever I execute the JAR file `gui_test.jar` on another PC, it give me the error shown below.

The classes in the package `gui_test` are:

- gui.gui
- StreamGobbler.java

### ERROR

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gui_test.gui.walk(gui.java:967)
at gui_test.gui.<init>(gui.java:1030)
at gui_test.gui$17.run(gui.java:1030)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch (Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)

at jaya.awt.Eyentgueue.dispatchEyent(Unknown Source)
at jaya.awt.EyentDispatchIhread.punpOneEyentForFilters(Unknown Source)
at jaya.awt.EyentDispatchIhread.punpEyentsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at jaya.awt.EyentDispatchIhread.punpEyentsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at jaya.awt.EyentDispatchIhread.punpEyents(Unknown Source)
at jaya.awt.EyentDispatchIhread.punpEyents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EyentDispatchIhread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions to resolve the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the other machines the same OS? Are they all 32bit, 64bit, or a mix? Have you tied a simpler version of your code on those other machines?

Comment: typos in standard exception stack message are strange

Comment: Since the error is occurring in `gui_test.gui.walk`, I'd suggest focusing on that bit of code.  Post it here for review.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to include a required resources. Be nice to see the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are possible.

1. You have developed it in a new version of Java, and the "other" machine is having an old version
2. Issues in JRE of the other machine
3. Problems with the build. Try a clean > rebuild in netbeans

That's all I can think about. Try this in another few machines, which has the same Java version, then only you can get the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Let me give a try and come back to you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Netbeans, But I do recall having problem importing a GUI from Netbeans into eclipse. This is possibly because the Netbeans GUI uses certain libraries.

Check this question, and this answer, it might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4498151/975959

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Let me give a try and come back to you again :)