# Export JAR in Netbeans with source

Tags: netbeans, jar, compilation

How can I export a **`.jar` file with source** (`.java`) in NetBeans?

Answer (score 9):

As simple as: 
      `Right click your project`  »  `Properties`  »  `Build`  »  `Packaging`

Verify that `Exclude from Jar File` filter does not include  ***.java**  files.
That's it! 
Your generated jar  will include source code.

[image: Project Properties]

Comment: From now on there will be no doubt on which version is in production.

Answer (score 1):

A JAR file is a Java Archive, and generally includes compiled .java files (classes) into a directory format based on packages.

Generally, you would want to provide your .java files (java source code) in a format other than a jar.

Netbeans provides the ability to export a Project from

> File > Export Project > To ZIP.

This will export the netbeans project along with any source code.

By default, The jar file is generated when you build your project in Netbeans and can be found in your "dist" directory inside your netbeans project. The "Files" tab (Ctrl + 2) in netbeans shows you your project files. You can right click on the jar file and find it's exact location on your computer by selecting properties.

See this question for more information on exporting a jar from Netbeans: [Export JAR with Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498047/export-jar-with-netbeans?rq=1)