# How to make a standalone application in java

Tags: java

I use eclipse to run my java code, but I want to make an application that won't use eclipse to run. I want to make it work as a portable stand alone application that only uses the libraries I need.

Comment: For what platform? Do you want a jar? An exe? Is it going to be deployed somewhere that already has Java installed?

Comment: You can export your project to `jar`, select class with main method that should be run when someone execute jar`, also lets not forget to include all libraries.

Comment: Information on how to do that can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/q/423938/586621

Answer (score 10):

Right click on Projectfolder (in Eclipse) -> Export -> Java -> runnable JAR -> choose class with main method. Done ;)

Comment: thank you for helping,I am sorry for bad English and unclear question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume you mean to create a *.exe* file. for this you'll need a *.jar* file.

I'm not familiar with Eclipse I know that Netbeans makes the .jar file automatically once the code is compiled.

(For Netbeans)
This .jar file can be found in the *dist* folder. In case there is none see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498047/export-jar-with-netbeans) to fix that.

In case Eclipse puts into a different folder I'd just look in all the folders related to the project until you find a file with a .jar extension.

Once you have the *.jar* file you'll need to run an application to change it from *.jar* to *.exe* , I would recommend [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html).

[Here's](http://www.how2java.com/2012/05/launch4j-convert-jar-file-to-exe-file.html) a handy tutorial to help you with that application if you get stuck.

I know this isn't *exactly* the answer you're looking for but it's close! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot,I am new to java so my questions may be a little unclear,I needed to know how to make .exe file.I found it,thanks.

Comment: I'm just as new I'm sure. I just happened to be looking for the same thing just a little earlier. In my search for an answer I found this question then just provided what I'd found once I'd gotten an answer. Maybe edit your question to help others with the same problem