# image doesn't diplay in jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a netbeans java GUI project. It contains java files and folder for images. A most important piece of my project is to display image by clicking a button, let's say it NEXT button. When I clicked NEXT button, image will be displayed one by one from IMG folder. I put the image in a label, like this:

```
lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../IMG/"+ namaGambar[gambarPos])));
```

I run the program and so far, it works as I want.

Then, I need to create the project into a jar file. I followed [Export JAR with Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498047/export-jar-with-netbeans?answertab=active#tab-top) and [this](http://www.javaquery.com/2011/12/how-to-create-jar-file-in-netbeans.html) to create jar file of my project and  finally I got myProject.jar file in ./dist/ directory.

When I run myProject.jar, I found that there's something wrong. When I clicked NEXT button, the image doesn't display like I've tried in netbeans. I confuse, did I do something wrong in `lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../IMG/"+ namaGambar[gambarPos])));`
or what's the problem here?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify where your images are saved. Are they added to the jar file?

Comment: Extract the jar file & verify whether the image file is in correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get resources in a jar using `"/" + zip entry name of the data`.

Assuming your jar file looks like this:

```
xyz.jar
   |------IMG
   |       |-------picture1.png
   |       |-------picture2.gif
   |       |-------picture3.jpeg
   .       .
   .       .
   .
   |------org
   .       |-------example
   .       .          |---------MyClass.class
   .       .          .
   .       .
   .
```

You have to use

```
"/IMG/"+ namaGambar[gambarPos]
```

as parameter for `Class.getResource`.

---

NetBeans runs programs from folder `build/classes` and not from the jar file. That explains the different behaviour.