# Build as single jar with dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I am using netbeans IDE 7.4. I want to make a jar file with all my dependencies and other image folders along with the jar. How to make a single workable jar file in netbeans or in command tool.

Thanks

Comment: You could look at things like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Can't i do it in netbeans?

Comment: `OneJar` has a Ant task which can be included in your `build.xml` to generate the output as part of your normal build process..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498047/export-jar-with-netbeans

Comment: @Ubica I know to export as jar. I want to export jar with all its dependencies.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: @madprogrammer.. 
I followed http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart 
Error
A:\tmp\test-one\test>ant
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Bass you need to set `PATH` variable for windows environment... so that system knows where to find `ant`

Comment: @Ubica. I already set path variable. i get other error while execute the below command
A:\tmp\test-one\build>java test -jar test-one.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class test

Comment: well something is wrong with your main class, or your main class is not called test :)

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use some build tool. Gradle provides [java](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) and [java-library-distribution](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/javaLibraryDistribution_plugin.html) plugins that makes distributing artifacts simpler (less code).

Follow [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-our-first-java-project/) blog for getting started with gradle. It should be simple & quick.

Comment: Is there any easy way to do that using command line tool or in netbeans?

Comment: Why do you think gradle would not be easy? :)

Comment: I have not yet heard about this and don't know how to work on this. Can you give me sample working tips on this?

Comment: Its really good. But for now, i have project in netbeans and just want to export a single jar with all dependencies. As @MadProgrammer said OneJar is a good tool to achieve my requirement. Thanks for your effort.