# Use external project in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, mp4parser

I downloaded a project from Google Code named 'mp4parser'.

Now I want to use it in my JSP page (specifically in a servlet).
How do I import it?

I use Netbeans.

In my project's properties I added a Library (Add JAR/Folder).

Then, in my servlet code I wrote

```
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.*;
```

But I get an error 'package don't exist'.

### SOLVED

First I had to compile the mp4parser project, and then MANUALLY indicate the JAR file.
Netbeans couldn't find it on its own.

Comment: you need to add the project's jar in your classpath.

Comment: but the project I downloaded doesn't contain any JAR files

Comment: if i am correct they provide jar for download, have a look at there page to add dependencies using maven,what all is there in your downloaded files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [create jar of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602537/producing-executable-jar-in-netbeans) you downloaded and the [add it to the class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) and then you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

So you get compile time error ? The only problem that is happeing is your Jar is not in the Build Path. Please check [How to add jar in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)