# Make executable in Netbeans

Tags: java, testing, netbeans, executable

I want to executable my program, but if I click on Run -> Test Project appears:

```
    ant -f "D:\\Aplicatii netbeans\\Licenta\\ProgramareInRetea07august"
-Dnb.internal.action.name=test -Dignore.failing.tests=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true test
    init:
    deps-jar:
    Updating property file: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\built-jar.properties
    init:
    deps-clean:
    Updating property file: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\built-clean.properties
    Deleting directory D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build
    clean:
    Created dir: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\classes
    Created dir: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\empty
    Created dir: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
    Compiling 12 source files to D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\classes
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    Copying 8 files to D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\classes
    compile:
    Created dir: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\test\classes
    compile-test:
    Created dir: D:\Aplicatii netbeans\Licenta\ProgramareInRetea07august\build\test\results
    No tests executed.
    test-report:
    test:
```

So what can I do?

Comment: Do you want to run your main method from within the IDE or do you want to create a executable jar?

Comment: "Run Test project" looks for jUnit tests.  This only works if you have them.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Producing executable jar in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602537/producing-executable-jar-in-netbeans)