# My java application can be opened with java -p -m command, but not with java -jar or double clicking

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

My project is an edited version of r0d0t's InfEncoder. You can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Rodot/InfEncoder).

What I modified is mainly support for Java 10, and that's fixing broken references and deprecated libraries. My current code is available [here](https://github.com/MiLeG/InfEncoderusp=sharing).

When I build the project in NetBeans it shows the following message:

"To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1/bin/java -p C:\projects\InfEncoder-master\dist\InfEncoder.jar -m InfEncoder"

The command works fine and runs the code. However, what I am trying to do is to run the .jar file by double-clicking it or with the java -jar command, but the whole idea is to make r0d0t's original project run with Java 10.

EDIT: Since some deprecated libraries needed to be included in the project, NetBeans created a module-info class which states

```
module InfEncoder {
requires java.activation;
requires java.desktop;
requires java.base;
requires java.logging; }
```

This could be why the command `-p` has `"InfEncoder"` as the value. When running the project the entry module needs to be the one with referenced libraries in module-info. I have confirmed this by putting InfFrame instead of InfEncoder in the module-info class and the command that netbeans gives changes the entry module.

Comment: As many people I'm not willing to visit an unknown google drive. So I can't see the code. How are you bilding your jar? Do you use maven? If you do you should have a look at the assembly or shade plugin. If not you could probably use an "export as runnable jar" (or similar) routine of your IDE.

Comment: The code is now on GitHub, rather than google drive. I am building my jar in Netbeans, without maven. I am quite new and am not aware of an "export as runnable jar" option in Netbeans

Comment: Probably this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602537/producing-executable-jar-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run a Java application from a jar using the `java -jar` command or by double-clicking the jar, the jar's `META-INF/MANIFEST` file has to contain a `Main-Class` attribute, e.g.

```
Main-Class: com.my.App
```

if `com.my.App` is the fully qualified name of the class containing the application's main method.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. My manifest looks like this:

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.1
Created-By: 10.0.1+10 ("Oracle Corporation")
Main-Class: infencoder.InfFrame
Class-Path: .lib/*`

I am positive that InfFrame is my main class (it contains the main method).

Comment: The `Class-Path: .lib/*` entry is not correct. `Class-Path` does not support wildcards, see (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). Moreover, is there really a `.lib` directory? It is kind of unusual to prefix library directories with a dot.

By the way, what **does** happen if you run the application from command line using the `java -jar` command?

Comment: Okay, I have checked if commenting out the incorrect line would help, and I came to a conclusion that the changes I make to the manifest don't apply after I build the project. When I do compile it with java -jar it brings up errors of undefined classes that i have included in the lib folder. The errors do not show up when using the java -p -m command, though.

Comment: Maybe that is because (according to documentation) you are using the `-p` option wrong: its argument should be a list of **directories**. I guess the JVM is lenient, ignores the fact that you are specifying a file, and just uses the `C:\projects\InfEncoder-master\dist` as search path (which would explain why it is working if your `lib` directory is a subdirectory of `dist`.

Comment: `lib` is not a subdirectory of `dist`, that I am sure of. The command itself is presented in the NetBeans compiler, so I assumed it didn't have any errors. Isn't `-p` the command to specify where the module to be loaded with `-m` is? My guess is it reads the .jar file just like a directory and loads the module "InfEncoder" from it.